# Google Smarthome Local Fulfillment SDK onQuery

Tags: google-smart-home

I am currently implementing a local fulfillment path for my IoT device integration with Google Home. Following [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/local/classes/smarthome.app), I can see that the smarthome.App Class lets one define handlers for onIdentify, onReachable and onExecute, but I cannot see anything for onQuery. Is this simply not possible or am I missing a point here?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

QUERY events are not part of the Local Home SDK. This intent should be handled in the server fulfillment logic.